# Compilation error when instantiating templated std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++17, std-function

I want to pass a functor that accepts a templated argument to a templated function. Something like this:

```cpp
// Generic translator
template <typename T>
int foo(T arg, std::function<int(T)> translate) {
  return translate(arg);
}

// Concrete translator
int chartoint(char c) {
  return static_cast<int>(c);
}

// Call site
void main() {
  foo('p', chartoint); // compilation error here
}
```

I get `Candidate template ignored: could not match 'function<int (type-parameter-0-0)>' against 'int (*)(char)'` error.

1. Why doesn't it work?
2. How to make it work?

Thanks!

*EDIT:*
This works for some reason:

```cpp
void main() {
  std::function<int(char)> chartoint_local = chartoint;
  foo('p', chartoint_local); // Works.
}
```

The original questions still stand. If I could do this without extra variable would be happy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The immediate reason for your error is the fact that in

```
 int foo(T arg, std::function<int(T)> translate)
```

`T` for `std::function` is in non-deduced context. The easiest (albeit unpleasant) way to fix would be to provide template argument explicitly:

```
foo<char>('p', chartoint); // no compilation error here
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Why cannot the compiler deduce <char> type from the argument 'p'? Because of all the implicit conversions?

Comment: Yes, function pointer is not `std::function<>`, and conversions are need to arrive from one to ta another.